# I use plastic 2 x 4 electrical j boxes and the 2 t retainer tabs keep breaking off months after install what am I doing wrong or is there a better?

Tags: drywall

Screw tight retainer Tabs on plastic 2x4 electrical boxes keep breaking off in wall months after install.

Comment: There's honestly no good reason to use plastic boxes. They don't even cost less than metal, and they are inferior in every way.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, If the metal box is being installed without attachment to a stud, what device do you recommed to clamp it to the back side (inside) of drywall?

Comment: Buy an old work steel box and use the clamps built into it...

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use metal old work boxes instead of the plastic ones. The template that comes with the plastic boxes is usually too big, you have to carefully trace and cut the smallest hole for the box. The plastic ones are OK for switches but often fail when used for outlets because of the pushing and pulling of the plugs. There are plastic boxes that attach to studs if you're dead set on using them. You might have to do a little drywall patching but the tab issue will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

You are over tightening the screws to the tabs. Do not use a drill. Use an old fashioned screwdriver.

When you feel a bit of resistance  STOP.  Tightening further stresses the plastic around the screws, softening and degrading it. After a few periods of stress the plastic breaks.

Comment: I think you're also implying to use a hand screwdriver, not a drill. A lot of people don't realize hand screwdrivers are a thing lol.

Comment: OH heck yes!   I totally forgot that people use a drill.  I need to state that. Thanks

Comment: It can also help to pre-screw the tabs before you install the box, when you're able to hold the tabs as you screw them in.  Basically run the screw all the way into the tab and back it out again.  This loosens up the threads in the tabs so it's easier to do when the box is in place.